# ASP.NET Core - Get tuple with two values

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I just want to get the user's role and ID from the user table. But I do not know why the following code gives an error!!!

```cs
public Tuple<Guid,Guid> GetUserId(string mobile)
{
    return _context.Users.Select(u => new Tuple<Guid,Guid,Boolean>(u.UserId,u.RoleId,u.Mobile == mobile));
}
```

I searched a lot but did not find an answer?

Error:

[image: error image]

Comment: Can you please provide the error?

Comment: @AjayGupta Can't convert from bool to string - This gives the error

Comment: Still not sure what you're achieving. Your `_context.Users.Select()` will return `IEnumerable<Tuple<Guid,Guid,string>>` which un-match with the method return type `Tuple<Guid,Guid>`.

Comment: @sunboy_sunboy your return type is not matching with your codes, have a look to my answer for fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile, your existing code will return `IEnumerable<Tuple<Guid,Guid>>` or `IQueryable<Tuple<Guid,Guid>>`, which un-match with the method return type, `Tuple<Guid,Guid>`.

Assume that you are trying to filter with `mobile`.

You need either of these methods:

- [`.First()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=net-6.0)
- [`.Single()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?view=net-6.0)
- [`.FirstOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-6.0)
- [`.SingleOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=net-6.0)

to return (single) result `Tuple<Guid,Guid>`.

```cs
public Tuple<Guid,Guid> GetUserId(string mobile)
{
    return _context.Users
        .Where(u => u.Mobile == mobile)
        .Select(u => new Tuple<Guid,Guid>(u.UserId,u.RoleId))
        .First();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting errors for casting as you are converting boolean to string.

```
u.Mobile == mobile
```

it will return Boolean value, not a string.

correct code

```
 public Tuple<Guid,Guid> GetUserId(string mobile)
    {
        return _context.Users.Select(u => new Tuple<Guid,Guid,Boolean>(u.UserId,u.RoleId,u.Mobile == mobile));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gives an error again. I put the photo of the error in my questions

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with your method defíntion.
Your method's return type is
**Tuple<Guid,Guid>**  but you returnig values as **Tuple<Guid,Guid,Boolean>**  which it is not matching.

Just update the method return tpye tupple as:

```
public Tuple<Guid,Guid, Boolean> GetUserId(string mobile)
{
    return _context.Users.Select(u => new Tuple<Guid,Guid,Boolean>(u.UserId,u.RoleId,u.Mobile == mobile));
}
```

Comment: No this is not true

Comment: @sunboy_sunboy what is not true ? your method return type is tupple<Guid, Guid> but you returning Tuple<Guid,Guid,Boolean> , it is not matching. Just try as I posted.

Comment: You have to update method return type or your select statement.